# Is there anyway to disable Product Approved Notification from Magento Admin site?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am currently using magento 2.3 and when I disabled or enabled a product on magento admin site, seller got Product Approved Notification. If I disabled 100 products, seller got 100 Product Approved Notification emails. So is there anyway to disabled that kind of email alert from magento admin site.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot settings]

Is it this mail?

Stores > Configuration > catalog > catalog > Product Alerts

Comment: No it is not , I just already disabled that product alert.